Filter or Query or Index? Need to return a list of names from people who have a specific value in a cell
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JGWoO94ic2O8SMq6JVKrlIIzqRVlf1vFVvHCVZ4pxuM/edit?usp=sharing
Using the link above I have names in row 1 from K1:HT1
I have the current status value in Row 49
if a name has a value of B-Fail under it I would like a list of all those names to display in IC2 or IC3.
I have tried filters, queries, and index with little luck and am unsure which would be best here. Any help would be appreciated. I have hidden all irrelevant data. Just would like it to list these names when it matches "B-Fail".


You may try:
=filter(scan(,K1:HT1,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),K49:HT49="B-Fail")



Thank You! I don't think i would have figured out the lambda portion.
